# How to upload and save files in specific locations based on their names?

Tags: java, jsp, file-io, struts2

I need to upload files and save them in specific locations based on their names. 
I am using the following code but not sure how to save them based on their names.
Currently it gives me the following error.

```
SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Jsp

```
    <s:form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="on" 
             action="myforms">
                       .......
                   <s:textfield name="Name" label="Name"/>
                    <s:file name="logo" label="Upload Logo" size="40"/>
        <s:submit validate="true"></s:submit>
```

Action

```
 @Action
 public class MyFormHandler implements ModelDriven{
  private FormData formData;
  private File logo;

  public String myforms(){
     System.out.println(formData.getName());   // << it works
     System.out.println("file name:" + logo.getName());   << Error
  }

   public File getLogo() {
    return logo;
}

public void setLogo(File logo) {
    this.logo = logo;
}

   ......
 }
```

Comment: You tried to invoke a null object, when did you expect it to get initialised?

Comment: The the form is filled up and the file is selected user click on submit and the system try to process the request in myforms() method, as shown I can access to the name field that is submitted but I do not have access to logo variable to access to uploaded file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show makes no sense on its own; the uploaded file will be in `File logo` (assuming proper getters/setters etc.) and I have no clue what `FormData` is.

Your best bet is to copy the uploaded file to whatever directory you want based on its name, but without further info it won't be easy to ascertain what's going wrong in your case.

Comment: thanks dave for you response, I have updated the question, actually formData is a class that ModelDriven will populate when the form is submitted.

Comment: @DanielMorgan If you're using ModelDriven why isn't the file in the model? I *think* S2 should still find the logo property since it'll search the stack, but I'd have to verify that.

Comment: I suppose it does not because it gives the nullpointer error,

Comment: @DanielMorgan I'd have to be convinced the action was not pushed on the stack, however, which I find unlikely (e.g., I18N still works).

Comment: so what would be your suggestion ? I am confused !

Comment: do you know of any tutorial ?